# extract valus of another dataframe if value of one column is partially match in R

Tags: r

Sorry I didn't clarify my question,
my aim is if dt$id %in% df$id , extract df$score add to new column at dt,

I have a dataframe like this :

```
df <- tibble(
score = c(2587,002,885,901,2587,3371,3372,002),
id = c("AR01.0","AR01.1","AR01.12","ERS02.00","ERS02.01","ERS02.02","QR01","QR01.03"))
```

And I have another dataframe like

```
dt <- tibble(
id = c("AR01","QR01","KVC"),
city = c("AM", "Bis","CHB"))
```

I want to mutate a new column "score"
I want to got output like below :

| id | city | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AR01 | AM | 2587/2/885 |
| ERS02 | Bis | 901/3371 |
| KVC | CHB | NA |

or

| id | city | score | score2 | score3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AR01 | AM | 2587 | 2 | 885 |
| ERS02 | Bis | 901 | 3371 | NA |
| KVC | CHB | NA | NA | NA |

I tried to use ifelse to achieve but always got error,
do any one can provide ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create groups by extracting everything before the `.` using `sub` to `group_by` on and merge the rows with `paste` separated with `/` and `right_join` them by id like this:

```r
library(tibble)
df <- tibble(
  score = c(2587,002,885,901,2587,3371,3372,002),
  id = c("AR01.0","AR01.1","AR01.12","ERS02.00","ERS02.01","ERS02.02","QR01","QR01.03"))

dt <- tibble(
  id = c("AR01","QR01","KVC"),
  city = c("AM", "Bis","CHB"))

library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(id = sub('\\..*', "", id)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(score = paste(score, collapse = '/')) %>%
  distinct(id, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  right_join(., dt, by = 'id')
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   score      id    city 
#>   <chr>      <chr> <chr>
#> 1 2587/2/885 AR01  AM   
#> 2 3372/2     QR01  Bis  
#> 3 <NA>       KVC   CHB
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Sorry about I'm not clarify my question, I have two dataframe (df and dt), I want to if df$id included dt$id , extract  df$score value and add into new column of dt, thank you.

Comment: @Alegría, I added some code to join the two dataframes.

Answer (score 2):

A simple `left_join` (after `mutate`ing `id` values in `df`) is required:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
left_join(df %>% mutate(id = str_extract(id, "[\\w]+")), dt, by = "id") %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(across(city,first),
            score = paste(score, collapse = "/"))
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  id    city  score        
  <chr> <chr> <chr>        
1 AR01  AM    2587/2/885   
2 ERS02 NA    901/2587/3371
3 QR01  Bis   3372/2
```

For the second solution you can use `separate`:

```
library(dyplr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
left_join(df %>% mutate(id = str_extract(id, "[\\w]+")), dt, by = "id") %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(across(city,first),
            score = paste(score, collapse = "/")) %>%
  separate(score,
          into = paste("score", 1:3),
          sep = "/" )
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  id    city  `score 1` `score 2` `score 3`
  <chr> <chr> <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    
1 AR01  AM    2587      2         885      
2 ERS02 NA    901       2587      3371     
3 QR01  Bis   3372      2         NA
```

Comment: Hi, Chris ! Thank you for all your assistance,  I really appreciate your help in resolving the problem.

Comment: No problem, always a pleasure. I'm still a little confused though because neither the accepted solution nor mine outputs the desired output. Is the mistake on our side or yours?

Comment: @ Chris Ruehlemann , in my real data is about 8042 x 7 columns ,  when I tried your code , I miss some rows, I still degbug! But  I still want to thank you.